# Is it possible to use mercurial bundles to move obsolencence markers?

Tags: mercurial

I recently tried to move changesets from one clone to another using bundle (`hg bundle -r 'not public()' --base <SOMEOLDREV>`). It quickly became apparent that despite successfully moving the changesets, obsolescence data was left behind.

Is it possible to make a bundle that moves the evolve obsolescence markers?